# Changing printing in classes

Tags: python, string, class, printing

I need help because I dont know what to do anymore:

```
class BellFord():
    def __init__(self, string = ' '):
        self.adjM = [[entry for entry in rows.split(' ')] for rows in \
                 string.split('; ')]
        self.rows = len(self.adjM)
    def Edges(self):
        A, Edges = self.adjM, []
        for i in range(self.rows):
            for j in range(self.rows):
                if i != j and A[i][j] != 'inf':
                    Edges.append((i, j))
        return dict(Edges)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.adjM
    def __str__(self):
        return self.adjM
```

Problem is my input is a string and looks like this :
inf -1 inf; 6 inf inf; 4 2 inf
If I try to print it, it returns:

```
string = 'inf -1 inf; 6 inf inf; 4 2 inf'
print(BellFord(string))
<__main__.BellFord object at 0x84704FD>
```

I want it to return

```
[['inf', '-1', 'inf'], ['6', 'inf', 'inf'], ['4', '2', 'inf']]
```

If i try that in my shell w/o the class it just prints it like I want.
Hopefully you can help me,... as always =^). Thanks for reading.

Comment: lol no. That happened due to copy paste.

Comment: Well, this is not the code that you are running, because doing `print(BellFord('whatever'))` would trigger the error `__str__ returned non-string (type list)`.

Comment: No its exactly the code I'm running and it returns <__main__.BellFord object at 0x84704FD>.

Comment: Well, are you going to edit your question to fix it?

Comment: @Selcuk Identation isn't my problem. This happened because of copy pasting it and submitting the question w/o overlooking it.

Comment: @TheDude: Copy the code you gave and paste it into a file. Run it.  It has the error that DanielRoseman mentioned.  Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @zondo I did all the minimal steps. My complete code is 100lines. But it's the second time that I defined __str__ in a class and now it doesnt work.

Comment: @TheDude: There were three adjectives in my sentence.  "Minimal" is not all it must be.  It must also be complete and *verifiable*.

Comment: @zondo this is all you need to reproduce my problem. I've made a new file only with the code above. And I get <__main__.BellFord object at 0x84704FD>

Comment: @TheDude: It isn't reproducable as mentioned in the comments.  Either you are using different code, or there is something else at work; but nobody here can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @zondo What else can I do? The Edges function isn't mandatory for reproducing it. That's exactly the way I cast it in my shell and the described return occures.

Comment: @TheDude: Pretend you are someone else who has come to answer this question.  Copy the code into a file and run it.  You should see an error.  Slowly add more code from the original until you instead get the output that you describe here.  Then, copy that code and paste it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an indentation problem. Move everything from `def Edges` onwards back one level.